# Storing v8::Local<v8::Object> in a class static std::vector

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

I want to store a v8::Local in a class static container of type std::vector.

It is `TheClass.h` :

```
class SomeClass : public node::ObjectWrap {
public:
    static void Init(Handle <Object> exports);
    static Handle <Object> NewInstance();
    static std::vector<Local<Object>*> container;
private:
    SomeClass();
    ~SomeClass();

    static NAN_METHOD(New);
    static Persistent <Function> constructor;
};
```

It is `TheClass.cpp` :

```
Handle <Object> TheClass::NewInstance() {
    NanEscapableScope();

    const unsigned argc = 0;
    Local <Value> argv[argc] = {};
    Local <Function> cons = NanNew < Function > (constructor);
    Local <Object> instance = cons->NewInstance(argc, argv);

    if(container.size() > 0) {
        return *container.at(0);
    }

    container.push_back(&instance);

    return NanEscapeScope(instance);
}
```

If I call The `TheClass::NewInstance` twice, The second returned object is not the same as the first one was.

```
Local<Object> instance1 = TheClass::NewInstance();
Local<Object> instance2 = TheClass::NewInstance(); // is not the same with instance 1
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and make sure `i` is the correct value every time you invoke `NewInstance`.

Comment: `NewInstance` is called twice and the `return *container.at(i);` is executed.

Comment: Right. Please see my previous comment so I don't have to repeat myself.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. Assuming `i = 0` The problem is still there.

Comment: That is not possible. Code elsewhere is causing this. Debug with a [testcase](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I know that is not possible actually I am talking about something special about `v8`. There is something behind `v8` that I don't know.

Comment: You return `instance` but push `obj` onto the vector the first time and _assume_ `i` is correct in subsequent calls. Too much is lacking in this post. Moving on.

Comment: If `obj` is a `Local<Object>` that you don't make Persistent, then the object you push to the vector will no longer be valid after the `NanEscapeScope()`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious You are right :( I wanted to simplify my question and edited it out the code. I made some mistakes in it. @mscdex how can I make Persistent a `Local<Object>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from type `std::vector<Local<Object> >`. I had to use `std::vector<Persistent<Object> >` and then store the object as a `Persistent<Object>`

```
container.push_back(Persistent<Object>::New(instance));
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `TheClass::NewInstance()` contains undefined behavior. You are pushing a pointer to `instance` into the vector but that object is *destroyed* once it goes out of scope (i.e. returning from the function). Since `instance` has automatic storage duration it likely lives on the stack and the memory it occupies will eventually be overwritten. The next time you access that element in the vector it is no longer a valid object and any attempt to use it will be unpredictable. This means that when you access it the contents of the object will be random garbage and not the same as when you pushed it onto the stack.

How you address this depends on a wide variety of things but you can start by changing the vector to

```
std::vector<Handle<Object>> container;
```

and change the code that stores it in the vector to

```
container.push_back(instance);
```

This will allow `Handle` to be stored by *value* and automatically manage the lifetime of the object it references.